# How would I Push committed changes from my Working folder to the Origin for an Origin on the same local drive in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a SQL project where I do not want to share scripts outside of our office or place scripts in a private repo on GitHub.

I would like to use Git in Visual Studio 2022 to manage scripts in development using a master origin and workspace on my local C: drive.

> The problem that I am encountering is that I cannot `Push` committed changes from my workspace to my origin in Visual Studio 2022. I have detailed the steps that I used to create the origin and workspace below. I am wondering if I missed something in the setup that is causing the `Push` to be greyed out in VS2022.

1. I created a folder on my C: drive that I want to use as the `Origin`. The name of the folder is `C:\Projects\MasterRepo`. This folder is empty.
2. I have a folder on my `C:` drive called `C:\Projects\WorkspaceModel`. This contains all of the scripts that I want to put under source control. The `C:\Projects\WorkspaceModel` folder has the following structure:

```
C:\WorkspaceModel
|_\SQL
  |_\Diagnostic
  |_\Jobs
  |_\Reports
```

> SQL scripts `(*.sql)` scripts under development reside in each subfolder under `C:\Projects\WorkspaceModel\SQL`.
> `C:\Projects\WorkspaceModel\SQL` contains the scripts that I want to put under source control.

3. I created a folder on my C: drive named `C:\Projects\Workspace`. This will be used as my workspace and will be tied to my local Origin in `C:\Projects\MasterRepo`.
4. **Setup `C:\Projects\MasterRepo` as the master repository.**

   a. From the `Developer Powershell` in Visual Studio 2022, I issued the following commands:

```
PS C:\> cd projects\masterrepo
PS C:\projects\masterrepo> git init --bare
```

5. **Setup `C:\Projects\Workspace` as the workspace connected to `C:\Projects\MasterRepo`.**

   a. From the `Developer Powershell` in Visual Studio 2022, I issued the following commands:

```
PS C:\projects\masterrepo> cd..
PS C:\projects> cd workspace
PS C:\projects\workspace> git init
PS C:\projects\workspace> git add .
PS C:\projects\workspace> git commit
PS C:\projects\workspace> git remote add origin C:/Projects/MasterRepo
```

6. In Visual Studio 2022, Go to `Git | Local Repositories > Open Local Repository...` and select the `C:\Projects\Workspace` folder.
7. In Windows Explorer, copy `C:\Projects\WorkspaceModel\SQL` to `C:\Projects\Workspace\SQL`.
8. This shows all files as ready to `Commit` and `Push`. Visual Studio allows me to `Commit`. However, all `Push` options are disabled.
9. The following command successfully `Push`es the files to the Origin.

```
PS C:\Projects\Workspace> git push --all
Enumerating objects: 18, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 11.36 KiB | 298.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To C:/Projects/MasterRepo
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

### Questions:

1. I would like to use Git from Visual Studio 2022 for this case where the origin is on the same local drive as the workspace. Is there a modification to my setup that is needed to make this work? Have I missed something?
2. I would like to document this procedure for other developers in our office. Most have not worked in Git before. Is there a good reference for setting up origins on local drives that you might know of and recommend. I would be looking for references that are fairly granular in detail.
3. I also noticed that `commit` options are greyed out after staging. When I try `git commit -a` from the Terminal Window, I get the error:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn /usr/bin/vim: No such file or directory
```

Is the VIM editor installed with Visual Studio 2022? Does it need to be to use git?

### Workarounds

- Use `git commit -m "*message*"` in Visual Studio 2022 to commit staged files.
- Use `git push --all` in Visual Studio 2022 to push committed files.

Comment: `cd C:\projects; git clone masterrepo workspace` is a simpler and better way to create the initial clone (instead of init & remote add).